# Выполнение функции при переходе по site.ru/dir/#func

Tags: jquery

Здраствуйте.

Просьба подсказать: как, допустим, чтобы при переходе по `site.ru/dir/#func` выполнялась одна функция, а при `site.ru/dir/#func2` - другая функция jquery.

Пробовал `click()`, но нету эффекта.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: погуглите событие `hashchange` или воспользуйтесь специализированной библиотекой для [роутинга](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Routing)

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно, чтобы ф-я срабатывала при загрузке страницы в зависимости от хеша:

```
function func1 {
   ...
}
function func2 {
   ...
}

if(window.location.hash == "#func1") {
  func1();
} else if(window.location.hash == "#func2") {
  func2();
}
```

Обработчик на изменения хеша на странице:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    if(window.location.hash == "#func1") {
      func1();
    } else if(window.location.hash == "#func2") {
      func2();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

На страницу `site.ru/dir/` ставим скрипт:

```
$(function(){
    var h = location.hash;
    if(h == "func") {
       ...
    }
    if(h == "func2") {
       ...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Код прокрутки страницы на ссылку, если урл с якорем. Может коряво и не универсально, но работает.

```
function hashcontrol () {
 var otstup=100 //если есть верхний колонтитул с position:fixed
 var speed=1000 //скорость анимации
 var scrollof = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
    if (scrollof)   
    {
    scrollof=$("a[name^="+scrollof+"]") ;
    $("html:not(:animated)" +( !$.browser.opera ? ",body:not(:animated)" : "")).animate( { scrollTop: scrollof.offset().top - otstup}, speed );  
    }
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
    hashcontrol ();
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {   hashcontrol ();}); 
});
```