# Как вызвать функцию JQuery из url?

Tags: jquery, url

Как вызвать функцию JQuery из url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если url вида `example.com/#func1`, можно сделать проверку:

```
$(function(){
    var h = location.hash;
    if(h == "func1") {
       ...
    }
    if(h == "func2") {
       ...
    }
})
```

Это уже обсуждалось [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141680/jquery-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-site-ru-dir-func?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=141685#141685).

Answer (score 1):

Создаете файл (например file.html), туда записываете нужный код и просто открываете. Вообще, зависит от того, какая функция. Опишите.

Comment: скажем есть такой адрес: example.com/#function
чтобы через 'function' после загрузки сайта JQuery вызывал фунцию.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){//тут любой код...})();">
```

***PS***:
Можно и просто ввести любой код между `javascript:` и `;` но тогда не гарантия что браузер выполнит его весь.

Answer (score 1):

А может через парсинг window.location.href по-симпотичнее будет?